# Support for distance package in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm checking this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/r-packages-supported-by-azure-machine-learning#bkmk_D

to confirm wheter or not this supports the Distance package http://distancesampling.org/R/

Seems not, but I'm not 100% sure this is the right place to check it. Am I doing it right here?

Answer (score 1):

in order to confirm what are the installed R packages in AML Studio you could use an Execute R Script module with just the following lines:

```
data.set <- data.frame(installed.packages())
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

The supported Microsoft R Open 3.2.2 version in AML Studio includes 564 packages, you should visualize something like this in the Result Dataset port of the module:

[image]

Comment: Yes I already did that. I just wanted to confirm if that was the right  place to look for this.

Comment: That should be the right place. The point is that many documentation pages of AML Studio remain still outdated. So in my opinion this is the best option.